# How to find cortege with OneToMany relation in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA and have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="vehicle_entity")
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String type;
    private String vehicleRegNumber;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = com.transport.model.BookedTime.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="bookingTime", referencedColumnName="id")
    Set<BookingTime> bookingTime;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="booked_time")
public class BookedTime {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;
    Long startPeriod;
    Long finishPeriod;

}
```

And repository:

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Integer> {

   @Query("correct query")
    List<Vehicle> findAllByPeriod(@Param("startPeriod") int startPeriod, @Param("endPeriod") int endPeriod);
}
```

I need to find available vehicles, which not booked by time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for something like:

```
 @Query(nativeQuery=true, value = "select * from vehicle_entity v join booked_time b on b.vehicle = v.id where not (b.startPeriod > :startPeriod and b.endPeriod < :endPeriod)"
```

BTW I think that you might wanna try to change FetchType from `EAGER` to `LAZY` for `bookingTime` and then use `join fetch` in select query.

Answer (score 0):

So I found several solutions of my issue. The first one is offered by Enigo and the second one:

```
   @Query(nativeQuery = false, value = "select v from Vehicle v right join fetch v.bookedTime b \n" +
           "Where b.vehicle = v.id " +
           "AND (b.startPeriod < :startPeriod OR b.startPeriod > :finishPeriod) " +
           "AND (b.finishPeriod < :startPeriod OR b.finishPeriod > :finishPeriod)")
   Set<Vehicle> findAllByPeriod(@Param("startPeriod") Long startPeriod, @Param("finishPeriod") Long finishPeriod);
```